# Mongodb: db_name must be a string or symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my Rails 3.0.10 app, with Mongoid 2.2.2, I'm getting this error in production (works fine in development):

```
.../gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/util/support.rb:50:in `validate_db_name': db_name must be a string or symbol (TypeError)
```

I've added this to my environment.rb:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

Also, I've removed the `defaults <<` lines from my mongoid.yml file and replaced them with the defaults.

When I use mongoid-2.2.6, the app starts, but I get the same error when I query the db.

What am I overlooking?

## Solved

Needed to specify 'localhost' for the host rather than `<%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>`, and also specified the `database:` name.

Comment: Are you sure that correct mongoid.yml gets picked up? Seems like that no config (for that env) can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to specify 'localhost' for the host rather than <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>, and also specified the database: name.